# Reading Pdf, Doc, Ppt and xls files in android and ios using phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2, cordova-3

I am searching for the way to open and read Pdf, Doc, Ppt and xls files in my hybrid app developed using Sencha Touch 2.4 with Phonegap (Android & Ios).

**What i did so far**

1. I got to know by searching that Ios WebView supports Pdf, Doc, Ppt, But not on Android WebView. So i can't use WebView for both Android and Ios.
2. Device need to work in offline So, i can't use google doc viewer.
3. Tried [cordova-plugin-file-opener2](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) File Opener, But always getting "Error status: 9 - Error message: File not found"

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with inAppBrowser plugin

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

for iOS use

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('yourFileUrl', '_blank');
```

for android use:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('yourFileUrl', '_system');
```